# Translate Sql Query to DBContext query with filter Subquery

Tags: sql, filter, subquery, dbcontext

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ScheduleGroups A
INNER JOIN ScheduleGroupResources B ON A.ScheduleGroupId=B.ScheduleGroupId
WHERE B.ScheduleGroupId IN (SELECT ScheduleGroupId 
                            FROM  ScheduleGroupResources 
                            WHERE ScheduleResourceId=2)
```

I want represent with DbContext query.

Currently this:

```
return actualContext.ScheduleGroups
                    .Include(a => a.ScheduleGroupResources).ToList();
```

This brings me all results. I just want to filter as show in the 'where'.

Thank you so much for everything!

EDIT:

**I found the solution:**

```
return actualContext.ScheduleGroups
                    .Include(a => a.ScheduleGroupResources)
                    .Where(a => a.ScheduleGroupResources.Any(b => b.ScheduleResourceId == scheduleResourceId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, the original query can be written:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ScheduleGroups A
INNER JOIN ScheduleGroupResources B ON A.ScheduleGroupId=B.ScheduleGroupId
WHERE ScheduleResourceId=2
```

Comment: Maybe I forgot to say that the relationship was 1 to many.
No its the same result. your query only return the ScheduleGroupResources where ScheduleResourceId=2
My query returns all ScheduleGroupResources that are contained in the ScheduleGroups where ScheduleResourceId = 2
Anyway, thank you!